# Giving free subscription time (not trial) using paypal recurring billing

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Hey guys i tried searching so i hope this hasnt been covered.

We are building a gaming website that charges subscription. If we ever wish to reward a player with X free days of game time in the middle of their subscription period, is there a way to do this?

In other words if a user signs up on Jan 1 and he is billed for 1 month and it auto bills again on Feb 1 but for some reason we give him 7 free days, is there a way to change his billing date to Feb 8?

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am afarid that subscription can't implement such complex requirement, the best option is PayPal reference transaction. refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/?mark=reference . In this case, you can bill customer at any time if you want.

Comment: What about suspending their subscription? For example can we choose to skip charging them one month? So if i chose to give a user a free month it would skip charging them the following month and resume the month after?

Comment: Yes, you can subspend the subscription before next billing date to skip one month.

Comment: Great! Do you know where i can find the information on that? I am not a developer, i am asking for one of my developers.

Comment: You can refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/